# What is the environment after a sea is dried

Tags: science-based, sea

In a world where a portal has sucked the water from a small sea, what may the environment be like 30 years on from this event; only a salt water lake remains, infested by minions of chaos at the center.

Demons from the abyss created a portal at the bottom of the sea, then populated the lands as their territory.

Now adventurers have met a mermaid who wishes to rebuild her lost home.

They must find and convince a powerful wizard to help restore the sea by establishing portals to the plane of water along the basin of the valley of dread.

Comment: Removing all the water from the sea by portal would result in water flowing into it from all sorts of river and also falling into it as rain.  I don't think this scenario is plausible without something that removes those as well.

Comment: @Mary So I guess everything dies of thirst.

Comment: @Mary well i suppose thats what happens then. The daemons seeking havoc were smart to have this strategy. They leave a small lake of water at the centre of their power.

Comment: This question asked for a science based answers but includes unclearly defined magical elements.

Comment: @Slarty what’s the unclearly defined element? There’s no difference between a ‘magic’ portal and a natural hole in the earth.

Comment: I presume the sea in question is a continental, closed lake (like Big Salt Lake). If it's directly connected to the ocean (like Mediterranean), we may see something like [Zanclean flood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zanclean_flood). And if this sea is a freshwater open lake (like Great Lakes), rivers would refill it rather quickly.

Comment: @Andrew Richmond  if the mermaid, daemons and wizard are not needed and the question is just about draining the oceans then no need to include them.

Comment: @Slarty - They help give context to the question!

Answer (score 1):

Much will depend on the environment *around* the Erstwhile Sea. In other words, is the sea located in an already wettish or in an already dryish environment.

For purposes of this query, it's easiest to give an example of the latter. In fact, right here on Earth, evil forces have been busy transporting water away from a small sea:

[image: 1]

The Sunken Fishing Fleet you see in the picture used to sail on a sea that looked like this:

[image]

This is the Aral Sea.  Up until  the 1960s, it was a flourishing ecosystem, full of fish, Merfolk, and, of course, water.  Anymore, it's pretty much been sucked dry by Communist era irrigation projects and their ongoing environmental sequellae.  Sucks to be an Aralian Mermaid!

The environment around the Aral Sea has always been rather dry.  Now, while some areas upriver are moister, the sea itself is also dry.